# Segueing new storyboard from UITableviewCell of a UIPopoverController.

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uipopovercontroller

I have a `button`, on selecting the button I show a `popovercontroller` which is subclass of `UITableviewController`. When I select any cell in the tableview I want to push new storyboard.

I tried segueing through storyboard and it's not working.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {    

  var mainView: UIStoryboard!

  mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "storyBoardIdentifierDefinedinstoryboard", bundle: nil)

  let viewcontroller : UIViewController = mainView.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("controllerIdentifier") as UIViewController

  [self presentViewController: viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

You must define identifiers in storyboard if not you will get exception.